# Centos7 mysql can not start

Tags: mysql, centos7

Now I want to start mysql use `service mysqld start` on centos7,but I got the follow error:
OS: centos64 bit

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service Job for mysqld.service failed.   
See 'systemctl status mysqld.service andjournalctl -xn for details.
```

the follow had been installed without any error and warning:

```
mysql-community-bench-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-client-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-common-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-devel-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-embedded-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-embedded-devel-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-libs-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
mysql-community-server-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-test-5.7.5-0.6.m15.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

systemctl -l status mysqld.service

```
[root@www mysql]# systemctl -l status mysqld.service
mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Sun 2015-02-15 03:25:32 EST; 59s ago
  Process: 29844 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 29833 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29844 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS);         : 29845 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           `-control
             |-29845 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
             `-30168 sleep 1

Feb 15 03:25:32 www mysqld_safe[29844]: 150215 03:25:32 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Feb 15 03:25:32 www mysqld_safe[29844]: 150215 03:25:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Feb 15 03:25:32 www mysqld_safe[29844]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 164: 29987 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null >> /var/log/mysqld.log 2>&1
Feb 15 03:25:32 www mysqld_safe[29844]: 150215 03:25:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

journalctl -xn

```
[root@www mysql]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sat 2015-02-14 22:04:13 EST, end at Sun 2015-02-15 03:46:01 EST. --
Feb 15 03:45:32 www systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 15 03:45:32 www systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun shutting down.
Feb 15 03:45:32 www systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun starting up.
Feb 15 03:45:32 www mysqld_safe[1286]: 150215 03:45:32 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Feb 15 03:45:32 www mysqld_safe[1286]: 150215 03:45:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Feb 15 03:45:33 www mysqld_safe[1286]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 164:  1429 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/nu
Feb 15 03:45:33 www mysqld_safe[1286]: 150215 03:45:33 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Feb 15 03:46:01 www systemd[1]: Starting Session 2660120 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-2660120.scope has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-2660120.scope has begun starting up.
Feb 15 03:46:01 www systemd[1]: Started Session 2660120 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-2660120.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-2660120.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 15 03:46:01 www CROND[1522]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

cat /var/log/mysqld.log

```
[root@www mysql]# cat /var/log/mysqld.log
150213 03:00:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150213 03:00:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150213 03:10:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150213 03:10:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150213 03:20:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150213 03:20:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150213 03:30:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150213 03:30:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start this shell has bug when you don't config socket dir in the /etc/my.cnf file. so add the socket dir will be ok.
mysql 5.6.32 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

the log has this line:

> Feb 15 03:25:32 www mysqld_safe[29844]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line
>   164: 29987 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld
>   --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null >> /var/log/mysqld.log 2>&1

I would check the file perms on these directories.  Everything should be owned by mysql.mysql

I have seen mysql.sock problems in the past.  I also wonder about mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm when everything else is clearly 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks,but it does not work yet now even the file/directories listed by above owned by mysql itself.And I found I do not have the files:【/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid】
【/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock]】

Comment: On the right track. The missing files are the problem. Why your log doesnt say anything about that is confusing.  You should also check if your mysql instance can access the /tmp directory.  Here is a relevant post:

https://kb.hivelocity.net/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mount my /var/log dir to tempfs (laptop, energy saving). Commenting it out in fstab solves the problem, mysqld starts well again.

Changing the

> log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf
to a disk directory did **not** work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was 7 years ago, but also check that selinux isn't blocking it from starting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).